# Spring Boot Aspect @Around

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

I am using Spring Boot & try to log response time of every request.
For that purpose, I am trying to @Around Aspect.
Code :

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class XYZ {

       @Around("execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.service(..))")
        public void doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
            // start stopwatch
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Before");
            pjp.proceed();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // stop stopwatch
            System.out.println("Me here");
        }

}
```

The code gets compiled, but the issue is that when I am executing any controller method, nothing happens. I mean my SOP should get printed but they aren't.
What am i missing?

Comment: how is your endpoints configured in controller? Do you use @RequestMapping?

Comment: Yes, also same code is working when I am pointing @Around to My Controller, seems like I am unable to hijack requests to Dispatcher servlet?

Comment: Nothing happens because you told it to do nothing. Your aspect is basically destroying the call chain. You are always returning void, regardless of what the actual invocation did. An `@Around` aspect should always return the result of the call to `proceed()` and as such should return `Object` and not `void`. Also as you are using Spring Boot, just ditch the aspect and include the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` which already has those metrics (and more) for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
public void requestMapping() {}

@Pointcut("within(path.to your.controller.package.*)")
public void myController() {}

@Around("requestMapping() || myController()")
public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
   ...............
   joinPoint.proceed();
   ...............
}
```

Comment: Will it be accurate? I mean it will exclude lots of overheads that service methods execute? I have calculated the response time using this & compare it with actuator, there is time diff

Comment: I don't think that it is significant. how much is the time diff?

Comment: Combined version can be used:
@Pointcut("within(path.to your.controller..*) "
        + "&& @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void controllerMethodAnnotatedWithRequestMapping() {
    }