# How to log any outgoing responses from @RestController?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` to log any incoming requests on my `@RestController`.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public MyRsp ping() {
        ...
        return myRsp;
    }
}
```

The users will send `POST JSON` requests, which are already logged using:

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    return filter;
}
```

Question: how can I achieve the same for the JSON Response that I sent back to the user?

Comment: What if you add an interceptor that can log both request & response?

Comment: Well I thought there might already be an existing solution. As like above, for Requests logging there already is one using the `Filter`.

Comment: Write an `@Around` aspect. This way you can track both request and response at one place. See my answer here. This might help  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000449/spring-boot-aspect-around/44000673#comment75067284_44000673

Comment: But how can I access the content in the `@Around' method (eg the `JSON` output that is also displayed to the user)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to access the object(json) returned from your controller in your aspect? Of course you can do it

Comment: No I want to access the plain text content that is written back to the user. So I could log it (String). I don't want access to the object/bean itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why spring offers a rest logger that uses `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`, but does not offer response logging. Because it can be implemented quite similar to the req logging, as follows:

```
public class MyFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
        //same mechanism as for request caching in superclass
        HttpServletResponse responseToUse = response;
        if (isIncludePayload() && !isAsyncDispatch(request) && !(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
            responseToUse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        }

        //outgoing request is logged in superclass
        super.doFilterInternal(request, responseToUse, filterChain);

        //log incoming response
        String rsp = getResponseMessage(responseToUse);
        LOGGER.info(rsp);
    }   

    //equivalent to super.createMessage() for request logging
    private String getResponseMessage(HttpServletResponse rsp) {
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper =
                    WebUtils.getNativeResponse(request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);

        if (wrapper != null) {
                byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
                if (buf.length > 0) {
                    int length = Math.min(buf.length, getMaxPayloadLength());
                    String payload;
                    try {
                        payload = new String(buf, 0, length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                    }
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                        payload = "[unknown]";
                    }
                    msg.append(";payload=").append(payload);
                }
         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: its nice but it seems to consume the response, I'm getting empty payload in client, but fine payload on logs

Answer (score 0):

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
public void requestMapping() {}

@Pointcut("within(path.to your.controller.package.*)")
public void myController() {}

@Around("requestMapping() || myController()")
public MyRsp logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    joinPoint.getArgs()// This will give you arguments if any being passed to your controller.
   ...............
   MyRsp myRsp = (MyRsp) joinPoint.proceed();
   ...............
   return myRsp;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help. Because I don't need access to the BeanDTO, but to the text content that is sent back to the user.

Comment: In the above code, whatever is returned from your controller is captured in Aspect before sending it back to the user.

Comment: Yes, from my controller the `MyRsp` is returned as an object. And spring handles the rest automatically to convert it to a `JSON` response. I want to log that json text response that goes back to the user. But that is not accessible in the around cut?

Comment: why can't you just Autowire `ObjectMapper` and do writeValueAsString. In fact that is what Spring does internally for you

Comment: Ok I didn't know that. But what about the overhead if I serialize once more from the bean to json? Wouldn't it be better to just read/log the text that's already prepared being sent to the user?